# Spinner Message Issue

Tags: android, spinner, toast

I have a problem with spinner. When I open the class (where is spinner) automatically it selects me the last item on the list, but it don't show me a message in toast. And when I select the item by clicking it they appears me a message. What is wrong in my code?

Here is my code:

```
public class SelectCodIncidence extends Activity {

private ArrayList<String> datos;
protected netAppApplication app;
Spinner sp;  
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.codigoincidencia);
    datos = new ArrayList<String>();
    //datosCod = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        NotesCenter messageCenter = new NotesCenterImpl();

        List<CodIncidence> codincidence = messageCenter.getCodIncidence();                                      
        for (CodIncidence e : codincidence) {
            //datosCod.add("1");
            datos.add(e.id);

        }   
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        //  showMessage(ex);
            Log.v("blah", ex.getMessage());


        }
    sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, datos);  
    sp.setAdapter(adaptador);

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, android.view.View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                   int count = sp.getCount(); 
                if (count > 0){
                    sp.setSelection(count -1,true);

                    int item = sp.getSelectedItemPosition();

                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 

                                "Incidence Selected: " + datos.get(item), 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            return;
        }

    });
    }
  }
}
```

LOG:

> 01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944): java.lang.StackOverflowError
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.text.Styled.measureText(Styled.java:430)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.text.Layout.measureText(Layout.java:1655)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.text.Layout.getLineMax(Layout.java:689)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.text.Layout.getLineWidth(Layout.java:671)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.TextView.compressText(TextView.java:5150)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5129)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:5328)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.Spinner.setUpChild(Spinner.java:228)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:185)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:151)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelectionInt(AbsSpinner.java:292)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelection(AbsSpinner.java:269)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at Net.App.SelectCodIncidence$1.onItemSelected(SelectCodIncidence.java:64)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:854)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:977)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:161)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelectionInt(AbsSpinner.java:292)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelection(AbsSpinner.java:269)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at Net.App.SelectCodIncidence$1.onItemSelected(SelectCodIncidence.java:64)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:854)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:977)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:161)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelectionInt(AbsSpinner.java:292)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelection(AbsSpinner.java:269)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at Net.App.SelectCodIncidence$1.onItemSelected(SelectCodIncidence.java:64)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:854)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:977)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:161)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelectionInt(AbsSpinner.java:292)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelection(AbsSpinner.java:269)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at Net.App.SelectCodIncidence$1.onItemSelected(SelectCodIncidence.java:64)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:854)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:977)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:161)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelectionInt(AbsSpinner.java:292)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelection(AbsSpinner.java:269)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at Net.App.SelectCodIncidence$1.onItemSelected(SelectCodIncidence.java:64)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:854)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:977)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:161)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelectionInt(AbsSpinner.java:292)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelection(AbsSpinner.java:269)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at Net.App.SelectCodIncidence$1.onItemSelected(SelectCodIncidence.java:64)01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):   at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:854)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:977)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:161)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelectionInt(AbsSpinner.java:292)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelection(AbsSpinner.java:269)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at Net.App.SelectCodIncidence$1.onItemSelected(SelectCodIncidence.java:64)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
>   01-05 13:58:04.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:854)

Comment: so you want to make header in spinner with some text or you want toast of that last selected item??

Comment: I want to make toast with last selected item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your toast immediately after this condition 
like below mentioned

```
 if (count > 0){
    sp.setSelection(count-1,true);
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "Incidence Selected: " + datos.get(item), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to put the code like you said me (I had edited the code above) but when i open the class it gives me an error "Sorry! The application netApp (process net.App) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again", and the application is closing.

Comment: Yes, it is above. I was checking with "Log.i("","");" where is error. and the error is at this line "sp.setSelection(count -1,true);"

Comment: you have written "sp.setSelection(count-1,true)" two times. so just remove the second one which is written in click event and then try to run i hope error will solved

Comment: I just removed the second "sp.setSelection(count-1,true)", and I still get the error.

Comment: I'm going crazy with this. Is there any other way to get the last item of the spinner?

Comment: Ok, I solve it. I got tu put the toast before the "sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()".

Thanks for your help.